# Qual o comando para exibir a versão do WSL

Tags: linux, windows

Qual o comando no powerShell para ver a versão do WSL ?Já tentei: wsl --list --verbose não lista nada (Windows 10 versão 1909)

Comment: Abra o powershell e digite `wsl -l -v` se der erro você está usando wsl1. No wsl2 o comando funciona e exibe a versão atual do ws.l

Comment: Retornou: Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Uso: wsl.exe [Argumento] [Opções...] [CommandLine]

Argumentos para executar os binários do Linux:

    Se nenhuma linha de comando for fornecida, o wsl.exe iniciará o shell padrão.

    --exec, -e <CommandLine>
        Execute o comando especificado sem usar o shell padrão do Linux.

    --
        Mantenha o restante da linha de comando como está.

Opções:
    --distribution, -d <DistributionName>
        Execute a distribuição especificada.

    --user, -u <UserName>
        Execute como o usuá

Comment: Como atualizar para versão 2

Comment: Faça essa pergunta no [Super User](https://superuser.com/) que é outro site da nossa rede especializado em Operação de Software. Aqui a nossa comunidade é especializada em Linguagens de Programação. Detalhe, lá no Super User a pergunta deve ser feita em inglês.

Comment: Fiz uma busca no google e vi que atualização futura do sistema ( Windows 10 2004 ) vai atualizar para o WSL 2, por enquanto vou usar a um mesmo já que meu sistema não atualiza para o Insider.

Comment: wsl -l -v se voce digitar `wsl -` no terminal vai aparecer a lista de comandos disponiveis

Comment: Faça o acesso ao terminal do powershell como admin e coloque esse comando:
`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart` Ele é necessário pois você precisa ativar o `wsl` no windows. Após isso reinicie sua máquina e acesse novamente seu terminal e experimente rodar:
`wsl -l -v` Qualquer coisa mande na thread aqui.